# Recurrence relationship

Tags: divide-and-conquer, recurrence, master-theorem

Can anyone help in solving the recurrence relationship of a divide and conquer algorithm with the following equation?  I am pretty sure you can't use master theorem here because it is not in the form T(n/b) but may be forgetting a simple math rule here.  Please help.

T(n)=T(√n)+logn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that for some `k>0` we have

```
T(n) = log n + log n^{1/2} + log n^{1/4} + ... + log n^{1/2^k} =
     = log n + (1/2)*log n + (1/4)*log n + ... + (1/k) * log n
     = (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ... + 1/2*k) log n
     = (1 + 2^{-1} + 2^{-2} + ... + 2^{-k})log n
     <= 2 log n
```

from which it follows that `T(n) = O(log n)`. The bound `<= 2 log n` follows because `1+1/2+1/4+1/8+1/16+...=2` in the limit.